# UISearchBar is not displaying Scope Bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I use the following code to display a `UISearchBar` with a Scope Bar.

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;

searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil];
searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

[searchBar release];
```

However, the scope bar is never displayed. Why is it not being displayed and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in the `initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)`, the height is only the height of a search bar, not including a scope bar. Try replacing with something like:

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 90)];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(void) searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)
 controller{  
    _searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
    [_searchBar sizeToFit];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have UISearchDisplayController available, you could try using **UISearchBarDelegate** callbacks:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
  self.searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
  [self.searchBar sizeToFit];
  return YES;
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
  self.searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;
  [self.searchBar sizeToFit];
}
```